# Html parsing in javacc

Tags: html, parsing, javacc

I'm new to javacc and have been asked to extend a basic html parsing using javacc code.
My question - the `<script>` contains lots of characters - such as `>` and `<` that have other definitions.
For instance - `if(indexOf("?")) > 3`. I read about lexical states, but did not understand it much.

Could someone let me know how I can have multiple definitions for a single character. An explanation with an example would really help me.

And - is parsing the above mentioned example really required? How do you ignore such details?

Also, for a person doing basic parsing for a search engine, are some tags such as `<style>` required? If not, how do you completely ignore tags in javacc?

Comment: Perhaps that the [FAQ entry on lexical states](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#states) might help you to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want "<" and ">" to only be allowed in tags and end tags.  Except that between `<script>` and `</script>` tags, they should be allowed.  The following should do it

```
// In default state, "<script>" changes to IN_SCRIPT state
TOKEN : { <SCRIPT_TAG : "<script>" > : IN_SCRIPT }
// In both states "</script>" is recognized and goes to DEFAULT state. 
<*> TOKEN : { <END_SCRIPT_TAG : "<script>" > : DEFAULT }
// Other tags and end tags are only recognized in the default state.
TOKEN : { <OTHER_TAG : "<" (["a"-"z"])* ["/"] ">" > }
TOKEN : { <END_OTHER_TAG : "</" (["a"-"z"])* ">" > }
// Characters not in scripts, tags, or end tags
TOKEN : { <CHAR : ~["<",">"] }
// Characters in scripts
<IN_SCRIPT> TOKEN : { <CHAR_IN_SCRIPT : ~[] }
// Characters not allowed
TOKEN : { <UNEXPECTED_CHARACTER : ~[] }
```

Omit the last rule if you want a `TokenManagerError`, rather than a `ParseException`, to be thrown for less than and greater than signs that appear where they should not.

This answer is only intended as an illustration of the use of lexical states.  It is not intended to reflect the rules of HTML regarding less than and greater than signs, which I do not know.